# How to apply custom styles to the ng-bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I'm using the ng-bootstrap [datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker) (if you scroll down its the "Basic Datepicker") in my angular 2 application, but want to apply custom styles. How is that done? I don't see anything about it in the ng-bootstrap documentation.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to change its styling when putting css settings in the style.scss file instead of component's styling file

```
/*@src/style.scss*/

ngb-datepicker {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;

    .ngb-dp-header {
        background-color: rgba(52,104,191,1);
    }

    select {
        background-color: rgba(52,104,191,1);
        color: white;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of today you can provide a custom template for a data cell thus influencing look & feel of day display. This is demonstrated in the "Custom day view" section of the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker).

Comment: Here is a live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/IdmfO1kligliovJ5yRha?p=preview

Comment: I'm more looking to just style things like colors, widths, font sizes, etc.

Comment: What I'm pointing out in this response is all you've got today as customisation options.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource so what would be the easiest way to apply custom CSS? The only solution I see is just copy pasting the components code and replacing the styles.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the styles from:

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.scss

You have more scss files at:

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tree/master/src/datepicker

At the moment it is the only way to alter the styles of the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sass you only need to import _dropdown.scss in your bundle.

```
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/dropdown';
```

With this your date picker will float