# Applying CSS classes to custom day template in ng-bootstraps datepicker

Tags: css, angular, typescript, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

So I am using ng-bootstraps datepicker to display some user data for each day. I use custom day template to apply certain CSS classes

```
<ng-template #customDay let-date>
  <div
    class="custom-day"
    [ngClass]="evaluatePresenceType(date)"
  >
    {{ date.day }}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

The thing is this method is being called many times for each day which is less than optimal.
Is there a way to apply CSS class to every day just once, when the datepicker is being rendered and not every time I click anywhere?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214707/how-to-apply-custom-styles-to-the-ng-bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use a custom template day to give some class to "specials days" you has two approach:

1. Use `[ngClass]` or `[class.myClass]`="function(date)" as you
   indicate
2. Use `DayTemplateData` (see the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api))

Well, the doc is not very clear. The idea is to have a function,e.g.

```
  data=(date: NgbDate, current?: {year: number, month: number})=>
  {
    //see that futhermore the "date" you has an object
    //current with two properties: "year" and "month" that is showing

    
    return this.calendar.getWeekday(date)>=6?'square':null
  }
```

Then you use

```
<input class="form-control" [dayTemplateData]="data"
             [dayTemplate]="customDay" ...>
```

And your template day pass the "data" using let-data=data

```
<ng-template #customDay let-date let-data="data" ...>
  <span class="custom-day" [ngClass]="data" ...>
    {{ date.day }}
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

See that if you only want to apply an unique class your function can return **true** or **null** and use `[class.myClass]="data"`

In the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apujun?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-customday.html), I use the two approach and use two counters to show the improve of this another approach